# How to remove rectangle from custom ScrollBar?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, scrollbar

In the picture you can see the **white rectangle** in the right edge from my Listbox. How can i remove this or set the opacity for this element to "0.0"?

[image]

I can't find the element in code  (*I tried to change color properties of several elements to see wich element reacts*)

### Style/Template - Code for my Listbox and ScrollBar-Elements:

```
 <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Brushes used in Styling of ScrollViewer -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverBorderBrush" Color="#DDD" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="Gray" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedForegroundBrush" Color="White" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#FFEC1C1C" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListBoxBackgroundBrush"
        StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0.001">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.6" />
                <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="1.2"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="StandardBrush"
        StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="White" />
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush"
        StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!-- SrollViewer ScrollBar Repeat Buttons (at each end) -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border 
      Name="Border"
      Margin="1"
      CornerRadius="0"
      Background="{x:Null}"
      BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="0">
                        <Path
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
        Data="{Binding Path=Content,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                            Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!-- SrollViewer ScrollBar Repeat Buttons (The part in the middle, 
         not the thumb the long area between the buttons ) -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"></Setter>

        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!-- ScrollViewer ScrollBar Thumb, that part that can be dragged
        up/down or left/right Buttons -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"></Setter>

        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border
      CornerRadius="0"
      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="1" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar"
        TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border
  Grid.RowSpan="3"
  CornerRadius="0"
  Background="White" Opacity="0" />
            <RepeatButton
  Grid.Row="0"
  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
  Height="18"
  Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand"
  Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" />
            <Track
  Name="PART_Track"
  Grid.Row="1"
  IsDirectionReversed="true">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton 
      Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
      Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb
      Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"
      Margin="1,0,1,0"
      Background="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBrush}"
      BorderBrush="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBorderBrush}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton
      Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
      Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton
  Grid.Row="3"
  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
  Height="18"
  Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand"
  Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <!-- HorizontalScrollBar Template using the previously created Templates -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar"
        TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
  CornerRadius="0"
  Background="White" Opacity="0" />
            <RepeatButton
  Grid.Column="0"
  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
  Width="18"
  Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand"
  Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z" />
            <Track
  Name="PART_Track"
  Grid.Column="1"
  IsDirectionReversed="False">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton
      Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
      Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb
      Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"
      Margin="0,1,0,1"
      Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
      BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton
      Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
      Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton
  Grid.Column="3"
  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
  Width="18"
  Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand"
  Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <!-- Style for overall  ScrollBar -->
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!-- Style for overall  ScrollViewer -->
    <Style x:Key="FavsScrollViewer" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"></Setter>

        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>

                        <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
        Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                        <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

THX!

Comment: You don't use your `FavsScrollViewer` style which removes that Rectangle. Apply it in your main Style's template and it should be fine.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you! It works. :D